# Avaliação de Regressão Linear e problema com gráfico

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, machine-learning, regressão, sklearn

Meu problema está no fato de não conseguir plotar uma linha - gráfico de função de primeiro grau - em meu primeiro modelo de regressão linear. Como resultado, possuo linhas unindo os pontos de gráfico de dispersão das features de treino. Não consigo reconhecer se o problema se encontra em meu modelo ou na plotagem do gráfico.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui segue uma breve explicação sobre meu modelo que tenta prever a quantidade de cerveja ingerida.

Primeiro temos meu dataframe já limpo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui realizei a separação das amostras, com 70% das features servindo como treino e 30% para testagem do modelo. Como Parâmetro adicionei as colunas que desejo analisar, excluindo a `target`  - a que desejo descobrir, sendo a quantidade de cerveja ingerida).

```
x_train,  x_test, y_train, y_test= train_test_split(df.drop('Consumo de cerveja (litros)', axis=1),
                                               df['Consumo de cerveja (litros)'],
                                               test_size=0.3,
                                               random_state=42)
```

Então, armazenei na memória um espaço para a regressão:

```
model = LinearRegression()
```

E treinei o modelo com a feature e a target separadas acima:

```
model.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

Testei o score do modelo para treino e para teste - até onde entendi o score utiliza o calculo de R^2, certo?

```
model.score(x_train, y_train)  #resultado = 0.7063802238832536
model.score(x_test, y_test)    #resultado = 0.7437419586478451
```

obs: Uma pergunta adicional, seria por que os valores estão baixos? e se é normal serem tão parecidos. Mas esse não é o ponto da pergunta, creio eu.

Aqui tentei armazenar os dados de treino em um `numpy array` e modela-los para terem o mesmo tamanho

```
x = x_train.values
x = x[:, 0].reshape(-1, 1)
y = y_train.values.reshape(-1, 1)
print(f'{x.shape} e {y.shape}')
```

Os formatos foram : (255, 1) e (255, 1), formando duas series, como eu queria.

Nesse ponto tento plotar o gráfico para analisar a linha em relação aos pontos:

```
plt.style.use('seaborn')
plt.xlabel('temperatura média')
plt.ylabel('Consumo de cerveja(L)')
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.plot(x, model.predict(x_train) )
plt.show()
```

E o resultado é o mostrado mais a cima. Esperava uma equação de reta ideal mas obtive essa bagunça. Tentei alterar os parâmetros do meu modelo, armazenar as features e targets em outras estruturas de dados. Acreditei que o problema estivesse unicamente na implementação do gráfico `scatter`, mas já não tenho certeza.

Comment: Breno, bom dia! Consegue compartilhar o dataset? Abraço!

Comment: Claro! https://www.kaggle.com/dongeorge/beer-consumption-sao-paulo/notebooks  (fiz o download do dataset original nessa pagina do kaggle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importando o read_csv

```
from pandas import read_csv
```

Criando o dataframe e excluindo a coluna data

```
df = read_csv('./Consumo_cerveja.csv')
df.drop(columns = 'Data', inplace = True)
```

Removendo os valores NA

```
df.dropna(inplace = True)
```

Transformando string em float:

```
df.replace(',','.', regex = True, inplace = True)
df = df.applymap(float)
```

Separando X e Y:

```
X = df.drop(columns = 'Consumo de cerveja (litros)')
Y = df['Consumo de cerveja (litros)']
```

Separando dados de treino e teste utilizando o sklearn

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train,  X_test, y_train, y_test= train_test_split(X,
                                                    Y,
                                                    test_size=0.3,
                                                    random_state=42)
```

Criando o modelo de regressão utilizando o sklearn

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
model = LinearRegression()
```

Treinando o modelo:

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Avaliando o modelo:

```
print(f'Score: {round(model.score(X_test, y_test),4) * 100}%')
```

Aqui é a parte da impressão do gráfico:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from numpy.polynomial.polynomial import polyfit
plt.style.use('seaborn')

x = df['Temperatura Media (C)'].values
y = Y.values

b, m = polyfit(x, y, 1)

plt.xlabel('temperatura média')
plt.ylabel('Consumo de cerveja(L)')
plt.scatter(x, y)
# equação da regressão b + m*x
plt.plot(x, b + m * x, '-', color = 'red')
plt.show()
```

[Documentação do polyfit](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html)

Saída:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dê uma olhada no [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/regression.html), com ele fica mais 'fácil' fazer os plots que você quer.

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.regplot(x='Temperatura Media (C)', y='Consumo de cerveja (litros)', data=df);
```

Saída:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito obrigado, mesmo!! Sua resposta foi bem explicativa e clara. Não conhecia o polyfit do numpy e nenhuma aplicação do seaborn, com certeza vou aprender mais sobre ambas, obrigado pelas docs também. Tenha um bom dia!

Comment: Por nada Breno! Que bom que te ajudou! Seaborn vale a pena aprender! Abraços!